# How to make slideToggle element toggle back by clicking anywhere but the toggled element

Tags: jquery

I've got an issue where I'd like to make an element that is brought onto the screen using jQuery '.css' go back to where it was originally when you click anywhere outside of the element itself.

Basically a similar thing to lightbox, where you can click anywhere on the black overlay to close the lightboxed image.

This is the code I have so far which slides my element out from the top:

```
$( ".menu-toggle" ).on( "click", function() {
  $( '.slider' ).css( "margin-top", "0px" );
});
```

As ever, any help is appreciated! Thank you. =0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind a `click()` event on the document and check if the `target` is not `'.slider'`.

```
$(document).on('click',function(e){
    if(!$('.slider').is(e.target)){
        $( '.slider' ).css( "margin-top", "-150px" );//hide on top
    }
});
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much! I've been trying to find a way to do this for numerous projects of mine, and have never been able to work it out. Legend! :)